# Python Flask Gunicorn __debug__ variable to false

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I guess Python 3.5+ automatically assigns `__debug__` to true by assertion.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#debug__

I have my local testing environment (windows vscode wsl2) that I would like `__debug__` to be true, but in my production (Flask Gunicorn Ubuntu) environment I would like it to be false to manage directory asset and system call locations.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-O

I can use -O to remove all assertions and any code conditional on the value of `__debug__`, but how do I set `__debug__` to false in my production environment? Can't set -O, and setting debug=false in the gunicorn config file doesn't work either.

Right now I'm stuck flipping back in forth commenting out code between my testing and production environments.